# How to initialize lots of Android components in simple way

Tags: android

Is there any problems when I tired to initial all the components by create an object? 
There is just no reaction after I push the button.

My customize class:

```
public class ViewHandler extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Button btndo;
    public TextView text1;
    public EditText et1;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);

        btndo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btndo.setOnClickListener(btndolistener);
        text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    }

    private Button.OnClickListener btndolistener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            text1.setText("test");
        }
    };
```

My mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected ViewHandler viewtodo = new ViewHandler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewtodo.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear what your question is here. You are asking specifically about initializing components but the real problem appears to be that your onClick hander is not being reached. You should update the body of this question with the real problem you want to solve. You should also show what debugging steps you have taken to resolve this on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't extend Activity classes without any special needs. Use POJO instead of it and use composition instead of inheritance. It's more clean way

```
     public class ViewHandler {
        private Activity activity;

        public Button btndo;
        public TextView text1;
        public EditText et1;

        ViewHandler(Activity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        private View findViewById(int id) {
            return activity.findViewById(id);
        }

        private Button.OnClickListener btndolistener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                text1.setText("test");
            }
        };

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            activity.setContentView(R.layout.layout);

            btndo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            btndo.setOnClickListener(btndolistener);
            text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate an `Activity` class with `new` such as you trying to do with your `viewhandler`. Only the Android framework can instantiate an Activity.

Furthermore, an Activity with a child Activity doesn't really make sense- an Activity is like a window on a desktop computer. Windows don't contain other windows. Your `MainActivity` simply doesn't know what to do with the `viewhandler` Activity.

In this particular case, you should just move all your code from the `viewhandler` class into the `MainActivity`. If you want to move that logic into a separate class, your `viewhandler` should not be an Activity.

Comment: But if I don't extend AppCompatActivity,then I can't use findViewById

Comment: If you want to open another window, see: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: I just want to make my code clear in mainActivity.Just like program functions in C.Is it better to declare a method in mainActivity?